# How can I define an array to accept ordered pairs in a struct?

Tags: arrays, xcode9.2, swift4.1

import Foundation

struct locus {
        var x: Int
        var y: Int
    }

let aerodrome: [locus] = [(1,1), (2,2)]

produces error "Cannot convert value of type '(Int, Int)' to expected element type 'locus'"  I love that the compiler accepts 'locus' as a type - I hate that it doesn't accept the Ints I try and input.  Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your literal `[(1,1), (2,2)]`is an array of *tuples*. Try:

```
let aerodrome = [(1,1), (2,2)]
```

in the playground and option-click `aerodrome` and you'll get:

```
let aerodrome: [(Int, Int)]
```

If you want an array of `locus` you need to create instances of them. One way to do this is to use the automatic default constructor which requires named arguments:

```
let aerodrome = [locus(x: 1,y: 1), locus(x: 2,y: 2)]
```

If you don't wish to use the labels write your own `init`.